# Spring Boot, Sleuth, OTEL, and Honeycomb

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a scenario where I have Spring Boot integrated with OTEL and shipping to Honeycomb.io. I am trying to add an environment tag to each trace. I have created a class:

```
@Component
public class EnvironmentSpanProcessor implements SpanProcessor {

  @Value("${ENVIRONMENT")
  private String environment;

  Queue<SpanData> spans = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(50);

  @Override
  public void onStart(Context context, ReadWriteSpan readWriteSpan) {
    readWriteSpan.setAttribute("env", environment);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isStartRequired() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void onEnd(ReadableSpan readableSpan) {
    this.spans.add(readableSpan.toSpanData());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEndRequired() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have set break points in this class, and they never hit on startup, even though the bean can be seen in actuator. I have put breakpoints on:

```
SdkTracerProvider otelTracerProvider(SpanLimits spanLimits, ObjectProvider<List<SpanProcessor>> spanProcessors,
            SpanExporterCustomizer spanExporterCustomizer, ObjectProvider<List<SpanExporter>> spanExporters,
            Sampler sampler, Resource resource, SpanProcessorProvider spanProcessorProvider) {
        SdkTracerProviderBuilder sdkTracerProviderBuilder = SdkTracerProvider.builder().setResource(resource)
                .setSampler(sampler).setSpanLimits(spanLimits);
        List<SpanProcessor> processors = spanProcessors.getIfAvailable(ArrayList::new);
        processors.addAll(spanExporters.getIfAvailable(ArrayList::new).stream()
                .map(e -> spanProcessorProvider.toSpanProcessor(spanExporterCustomizer.customize(e)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        processors.forEach(sdkTracerProviderBuilder::addSpanProcessor);
        return sdkTracerProviderBuilder.build();
    }
```

in OtelAutoConfiguration and am not seeing them firing either on startup.

My pom.xml relevant section is:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
      <artifactId>opentelemetry-extension-trace-propagators</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
      <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
      <version>1.47.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my configuration from application.yaml

```
sleuth:
    enabled: true
    web:
      additional-skip-pattern: /readiness|/liveness
      client.skip-pattern: /readiness
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0
      rate: 100
    propagation:
      type: OT_TRACER
    otel:
      config:
        trace-id-ratio-based: 1.0
      log.exporter.enabled: true
      exporter:
        otlp:
          endpoint: https://api.honeycomb.io
          headers:
            x-honeycomb-team: ${TELEMETRY_API_KEY}
            x-honeycomb-dataset: app-telemetry
        sleuth-span-filter:
          enabled: true
      resource:
        enabled: true
```

I am getting traces, so it appears the system itself is working, however I cannot get my env tag added.

Preemptive thank you to @marcingrzejszczak for the help so far on my gist: https://gist.github.com/fpmoles/b880ccfdef2d2138169ed398e87ec396

Comment: I originally picked up this guide: https://itnext.io/running-spring-boot-apps-start-tracing-with-opentelemetry-in-minutes-a5d3dffc1ce1 to get the process started

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why your span processor is not being picked up by Spring and being added to your list of processors being registered with the tracer provider.

An alternative way to set process consistent values, like environment, would be to set it as a resource attribute. This is more desireable because it's set once and delivered once per batch of spans sent to the configured backend (eg Honeycomb). Using a span processor adds the same attribute to every span.

This can be done in a few different ways:

- If using AutoConfigure, you can set via [system property or environment variable](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/d2a8304b9b41aa26bbf78f45429808b0b7f391d9/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/README.md#opentelemetry-resource)
- Set directly on the resource during your `otelTracerProvider` method:

```java
resource.setAttribute("environment", "${environment}");
```

FYI Honeycomb has [OTel Java SDK & Agent distros](https://github.com/honeycombio/honeycomb-opentelemetry-java) to help simplify sending data that reduces required configuration and sets sensible defaults.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I will look at this setAttribute again, I tried it but I think I did it wrong in looking at the docs again.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working either. I don't know what it impacts, but right now I am just using default tracing OOTB, I am not creating any custom traces.